# How to silence Xcode code signing warning?

Tags: xcode, code-signing, suppress-warnings, code-signing-certificate

I'm getting this warning in Xcode:

[image]

This is not a build time warning, it comes up as soon as you open the IDE.

Our end product is built on a build server by invoking xcodebuild in a script with setting the Distribution configuration. The configuration sets the "Developer ID Application" code signing identity required for notarization and distribution, and therefore the process that the warning describes (manual building for distribution in the Organizer window) is not relevant to us. How can I tell Xcode permanently that "I've got it down, please stop bugging me and my teammates with these warnings?"

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "Build Settings" and click on the *confirmation* button.
Having said that, if I recall correctly, this suggestion will be presented again after any Xcode updates.

Comment: I use a script to generate the the xcode project. Is there any way to do this with a build settings option?  Or i would have to disable this many times a day and that sucks.

Comment: @Lothar Check out what the manual checking of the checkbox changes in the project file. I think it's a version number that records which version of Xcode you last updated the project file with. If you keep your script up to date to use the latest version always, I think you will not get the warning.